# accessing newly created directory in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm attempting to make a new folder, a duplicate of the input, and then `tar` the contents of that folder. I can't figure out why - but it seems like instead of searching the contents of my newly created directory - it is searching my entire computer... returning lines such as

```
/Applications/GarageBand.app/Contents/Frameworks/MAAlchemy.framework/Resources/Libraries/WaveOsc/Sine/Sine - Vocal 1.raw is a file
/Applications/GarageBand.app/Contents/Frameworks/MAAlchemy.framework/Resources/Libraries/WaveOsc/Sine/Sine - Vocal 2.raw is a file
/Applications/GarageBand.app/Contents/Frameworks/MAAlchemy.framework/Resources/Libraries/WaveOsc/Sine/Triangle - Arp.raw is a file
/Applications/GarageBand.app/Contents/Frameworks/MAAlchemy.framework/Resources/Libraries/WaveOsc/Sine/Triangle - Asym 4.raw is a file
/Applications/GarageBand.app/Contents/Frameworks/MAAlchemy.framework/Resources/Libraries/WaveOsc/Sine/Triangle - Eml.raw is a file
/Applications/GarageBand.app/Contents/Frameworks/MAAlchemy.framework/Resources/Libraries/WaveOsc/Square is a folder
/Applications/GarageBand.app/Contents/Frameworks/MAAlchemy.framework/Resources/Libraries/WaveOsc/Square/Square - Arp.raw is a file
/Applications/GarageBand.app/Contents/Frameworks/MAAlchemy.framework/Resources/Libraries/WaveOsc/Square/Square - Bl Saw.raw is a file
```

can you guys spot a simple error?

BTW, I know that the script to `tar` isn't present yet, but that will be easy once i can navigate the new folder.

```
#!/bin/bash

##--- deal with help args ------------------
##

print_help_message() {
    printf "Usage: \n"
    printf      "\t./`basename $0` <input_dir> <output_dir>\n"
    printf "where\n"
    printf      "\tinput_dir : (required) the input directory.\n"
    printf      "\toutput_dir : (required) the output directory.\n"
}

if [ "$1" == "help" ]; then
    print_help_message
    exit 1
fi

## ------ get cli args ----------------------
##


if [ $# == 2 ]; then
    INPUT_DIR="$1"
    OUTPUT_DIR="$2"
fi


## ------ tree traversal function -----------
##

mkdir "$2"
cp -r "$1"/* "$2"/

## ------ return output dir name ------------
##

return_output_dir() {
    echo $OUTPUT_DIR/$(basename $(basename $(dirname $1)))
}


bt() {
    output_dir="$1"
    for filename in $output_dir/*; do
        if [ -d "${filename}" ]; then
            echo "$filename is a folder"
            bt $filename
        else
            echo "$filename is a file"
        fi
    done
}

## ------ main ------------------------------
##

main() {
    bt $return_output_dir
    exit 0
}


main
}
```

Comment: Add to the question, how you call the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can tell you why it's doing that, but I'm not clear on what it's supposed to be doing, so I'm not sure how to fix it. The immediate problem is that `return_output_dir` is a function, not a variable, so in the command `bt $return_output_dir` the `$return_output_dir` part expands to ... nothing, and `bt` gets run with no argument. That means that inside `bt`, `output_dir` gets set to the empty string, so `for filename in $output_dir/*` becomes `for filename in /*`, which iterates over the top-level items on your boot volume.

There are a number of other things that're confusing/weird about this code:

- The function `main()` doesn't seem to serve any purpose -- some of the main-line code is outside it (notably, the argument parsing stuff), some inside, for no apparent reason. Having a `main` function is required in some languages, but in a shell script it generally makes more sense to just put the main code inline. (Also, functions shouldn't `exit`, they should `return`.)
- You have variables named both `OUTPUT_DIR` and `output_dir`. Use distinct names. Also, it's generally best to stick to lowercase (or mixed-case) variable names, to avoid conflicts with the variables that're used by the shell and other programs.
- You copy `$1` and `$2` into `INPUT_DIR` and `OUTPUT_DIR`, then continue to use `$1` and `$2` rather than the more-clearly-named variables you just copied them into.
- `output_dir` is changed in the recursive function, but not declared as `local`; this means that inner invocations of `bt` will be changing the values that outer ones might try to use, leading to weirdness. Declare function-local variables as `local` to avoid trouble.
- `$(basename $(basename $(dirname $1)))` doesn't make sense. Suppose `$1` is "/foo/bar/baz/quux": then `dirname $1` returns `/foo/bar/baz`, `basename /foo/bar/baz` returns "baz", and `basename baz` returns "baz" again. The second `basename` isn't doing anything! And in any case, I'm pretty sure the whole thing isn't doing what you expect it to.
- What directory is `bt` supposed to be recursing through? Nothing in how you call it has any reference to either `INPUT_DIR` or `OUTPUT_DIR`.
- As a rule, you should put variable references in double-quotes (e.g. `for filename in "$output_dir"/*` and `bt "$filename"`). You do this in some places, but not others.

Comment: Hey Gordon, thanks for your detailed answer. It is supposed to be recursing through the newly created OUTPUT_DIR.

Comment: @VincentRodomista In that case, I'd simply remove `main` and `return_output_dir`, and put `bt "$OUTPUT_DIR" at the end of the script (except that you should change OUTPUT_DIR to a different name). Also, use [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) -- it'll catch a lot of basic mistakes for you.